# Where to specify type parameter on ArrayList

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between casting on both sides:

```
List <String>myNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

versus:

```
List <String>myNumbers = new ArrayList();
```

and:

```
List myNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Should be on both sides. Could also do `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: If you do not specify the Type of ArrayList or List, then compiler will determine via the data you pass into this ArrayList or List. If you specify it, you must pass exactly the data type as you have specify

Comment: I think the title should be _Where to specify type parameter on ArrayList_

Comment: @TuyenNguyen If you don't specify the type, the type is `Object`. The compiler can't necessarily even see what you're passing to the list, let alone determine the type from it.

Answer (score 2):

The first example is type safe meaning if you attempt to add anything other than a `String` object into `myNumbers` list then you'll get a compiler error.

```
List <String> myNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The second example is also type-safe, the compiler will ensure only objects of type `String` are stored in `myNumbers` list.

```
List <String> myNumbers = new ArrayList();
```

### Raw Types

> A raw type is the name of a generic class or interface without any
>   type arguments.

When generics were introduced in JDK 1.5, the raw types were retained only for backwards compatibility with older versions of java. Though using raw types is still permissible, you should avoid them for the reasons below:

- typically raw types require casts
- raw types are **NOT** type safe and some important kinds of errors will only appear at runtime.
- raw types are less expressive & don't self-document in the same way as parameterized types.

The last example is a raw type meaning we can add all type of objects into `myNumbers` list, However, you should avoid them when you can.

```
List myNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**note** - if you do not specify the type, as shown above, every item within `myNumbers` list is treated as a type `Object`.

### Where to specify type parameter on ArrayList?

From the examples you've shown this is the preferred way:

```
List <String> myNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

However, you can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type parameters (`<` `>`) as long as the compiler can infer the type arguments from the context.

meaning instead of this:

```
List <String> myNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

we can do this:

```
List <String> myNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Regarding second example, please explain: "... but only when adding items directly onto myNumbers list". So, what would be the other way? I just can think of adding items via myNumbers.add("string here"). And it behaves like example one, that is, it forces to provide a String.

Comment: @JohnSmith I was referring to the fact that you could assign a raw type ArrayList which has items of type Object to the myNumbers list but you can ignore that because the second example behaves the same way as the first as in the compiler forces you to provide a string object. sorry I had a typo within my answer, I have updated it now.

Comment: So if the second example behaves like the first one, now the question is, why do I have to specify string type argument on both sides as in example 1? Why can I just define it only on the actual variable (example 2)? Can you please provide a real case scenario showing why it is better to follow example 1 vs example 2? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So lets go through each of them

```
List <String>myNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This is stating that the `myNumbers` list will only store `Strings`.  This compiles because the `new ArrayList<String>()` also constraints to 'String` objects only.

Moving on to your second example...

```
List <String>myNumbers = new ArrayList();
```

Same as before, the `myNumbers` is constraint to only storing `String` objects.  What is different is that the `new ArrayList()` will store any object, it is a raw type.  So this compiles.  `new ArrayList()` will hold `String` objects, so it compiles.  More can be read about constraints and type reduction this in section [18.2.2 of the Java Language Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2.2).  This falls under the topic of inference.

> Chapter 18. Type Inference
>
> A variety of compile-time analyses require reasoning about types that are not yet known. Principal among these are generic method applicability testing (§18.5.1) and generic method invocation type inference (§18.5.2). In general, we refer to the process of reasoning about unknown types as type inference.
>
> At a high level, type inference can be decomposed into three processes:
>
> - Reduction takes a compatibility assertion about an expression or type, called a constraint formula, and reduces it to a set of bounds on inference variables. Often, a constraint formula reduces to other constraint formulas, which must be recursively reduced. A procedure is followed to identify these additional constraint formulas and, ultimately, to express via a bound set the conditions under which the choices for inferred types would render each constraint formula true.

And finally your third example...

```
List myNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This one is the most interesting one because it introduces type erasure and raw types.  Essentially what is happening is that even though the `new ArrayList<String>()` is instantiated with the parameterized `String`, Java allows for this to be ignored to allow for Raw Types, and the concept and rules of erasure is how it is implemented.  At least that is what one can deduce from sections 4.8 and 4.6 of the Java Language Specification.

> 4.8. Raw Types
>
> To facilitate interfacing with non-generic legacy code, it is possible to use as a type the erasure (§4.6) of a parameterized type (§4.5) or the erasure of an array type (§10.1) whose element type is a parameterized type. Such a type is called a raw type.

Furthermore...

> 4.6. Type Erasure
>
> ...skipping several bullet points
>
> Type erasure also maps the signature (§8.4.2) of a constructor or method to a
>    signature that has no parameterized types or type variables. The erasure of a constructor or method signature s is a signature consisting of the same name as s and the erasures of all the formal parameter types given in s.
>
> The return type of a method (§8.4.5) and the type parameters of a generic method or constructor (§8.4.4, §8.8.4) also undergo erasure if the method or constructor's signature is erased.
>
> The erasure of the signature of a generic method has no type parameters.

Comment: They all introduce type erasure. The difference is in what the type is erased *to*. In the good case, 'String': in the bad case, 'Object'.